# Foundation interchange responsive images only loading img src

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

New to foundation.So far, I don't know why the interchange isn't working.  The only image that is working is img src.  None of the others are being dynamically generated.  It's not a bad path, so is the code wrong below or perhaps a javascript file is needed?  I have foundation.interchange.js along with the rest of the js files.

```
<img data-interchange="[img/small.jpg, (small)], [img/medium.jpg, (medium)], [img/large.jpg, (large)]" data-uuid="interchange-i2pip11r1" src="img/large-banner.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had problem with that and I was looking for a very long time to find the answer and finally I had to use just normal css for my images because I couldn't solve this problem.

```
@media (max-width: 1120px) {
    .map {
        width: 625px;
        height: 380px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 855px) {
    .map {
        width: 480px;
        height: 375px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 675px) {
    .map {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
}
```

`map` is a class for my image.

Answer (score 1):

This took me forever and we probably made the same mistake.

Your syntax is from Foundation 5. Remove the parenthesis from "small", "medium", "large". You should also remove the "src=" so it doesn't load the resource twice.

```
<img data-interchange="[img/small.jpg, small], [img/medium.jpg, medium], [img/large.jpg, large]" data-uuid="interchange-i2pip11r1">
```